# Como setar o Foco em um Componente do MVC

Tags: advpl

Tenho um **MVC** modelo 3.

Após a validação de um campo do cabeçalho(`formfield`), setar o foco para o `grid`.

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

Não é nada recomendável dar refresh na view dentro de uma validação do modelo. Portanto o correto é utilizar os mecanismos da própria VIEW:
na viewdef....

```
bBloco := {|oV,cId,cField,xV|MinhaAcao(oV,cId,cField,xV)}
oView:SetFieldAction("CAMPO",bBloco)
```

Para setar o foco no Grid:

```
Static function MinhaAcao(oView,cIDView,cField,xValue)
Local oGrid := oView:GetviewObject(cIDVIEW)
oGrid:SetFocus()
return
```

Comment: É legal ver outras linguagens por aqui, mas acho que podia dar uma enriquecida na postagem pondo um contexto um pouco maior (tanto na resposta quanto na pergunta, como mencionar em que momento que o FieldAction vai executar o codeblock, por exemplo). Apesar de eu ser familiar com dialetos xBase, não uso Advpl, o método é GetViewObject mesmo? Achei meio redundante.

Comment: Opa estou tentando difundir o uso do stackoverflow na comunidade advpl, vou tentar dar um contexto maior. O metodo é esse mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Caso nao tenha resolvido, voce precisa estar o bloco de código no `bGotFocus` da

```
FWFORMVIEW():AddGrid(<cViewID >, <oStruct >, [ cSubModelID ], <uParam4 >, [ bGotFocus ])
```

No `bGotFocus` eu fiz o trecho abaixo, como isso sempre que o `Grid` receber o foco ele volta para o campo que eu quero, com isso criei uma variável de controle para o mesmo.

```
oView:Refresh()
oView:GetViewObj("FIELDZZ5")[3]:getFWEditCtrl("ZZ5_QUANT"):oCtrl:SetFocus()
```

Comment: Sua resposta me trouxe mais dúvidas do que explanações. Por exemplo, o que seria `ZZ5`? O que isso influencia na `grid` qualquer de um sistema em MVC 3? A resposta do KillerAll, entretanto, mesmo em sua simplicidade e sucinteza ao extremo, conseguiu me explicar muita coisa

Comment: Desculpe a maneira que respondi, ZZ5 é a tabela que uso, vou mudar a explicação.

Comment: oView:Refresh()
oView:GetViewObj("MODELO DE DADOS")[3]:getFWEditCtrl("CAMPO QUE IRA RECEBER O FOCO"):oCtrl:SetFocus()