# ADVPL - Setar foco em um campo MVC

Tags: mvc, advpl

Tenho um ponto de entrada no cadastro de produtos, onde habilito a tecla <kbd>F12</kbd> para chamar uma função quando estiver incluindo um produto.
Esta função exibe uma tela (MSDIALOG) com facilitador de preenchimento e atribui valores alguns campos do cadastro de produto.

Preciso que, após fechar esta tela, seja setado o foco para um determinado campo do cadastro.

Como o cadastro de produtos está em MVC, existe alguma forma para fazer isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ainda não testei, mas talvez este link te ajude: [Como setar o Foco em um Componente do MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150088/como-setar-o-foco-em-um-componente-do-mvc)

Nele mostra como dar foco na grid, contudo talvez seja possível também dar foco na enchoice do MATA010.